# KendoUI datasource model for "recursive" object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm a newb in KendoUI and I'm trying to bind object like this:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
 data: {
  a:"A",
  b:{
     c:"C",
     d:"D"
    }
 },
 schema:{
  model:{
   fields:{
    a: "string"
    b: ???
   }
  }
 }
})
```

to the kendo Grid. It's alright with "**a**" property, but I have no idea how to bind (and is it even possible) the content of "**b**".
 Should I declare "**b**" as a separate DataSource?
I have googled a lot, but it seems, like I can't to formulate my problem correct...so, can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of binding is possible in kendo grid. you will be using something like the one given below

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
 data: {
  a:"A",
  b:{
     c:"C",
     d:"D"
    }
 },
 schema:{
  model:{
   fields:{
    a: "string"
    'b.c': "string",
    'b.d':"string" 
   }
  }
 }
})
```

This kind of binding works fine for me. Do check this out. If you are working with ASP.Net MVC, the posted JSON data is model bound perfectly too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my problem correct. It should be:

    data: {
      a:"A",
      b:[
        {c:"C"},
        {d:"D"},
        ...
        {n:"N"}
      ]
    }